# How to set default value in materialize autocomplete input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, autocomplete, materialize

I am using ASP .NET MVC for my web application. I am using materialize theme (css and js) for UI. I want autocomplete input and with materialize syntax it,s working perfectly. But I want to select first option on load(using code) and I couldn't find any reference for that.
Here's my code.

HTML

```
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <label for="autocompleteInput">Chainage Number</label>
                <input type="text" id="autocompleteInput">
            </div>
```

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Vids/GetChainageNoList",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    firstChainageVal = item.ChainageNo;
                }
                chainageDataKeys.push(item.ChainageNo);
                chainageDataValues.push(null);
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < chainageDataKeys.length; i++) {
                keyValues[chainageDataKeys[i]] = chainageDataValues[i];
            }
        }
    })
   
    $('#autocompleteInput').autocomplete({
        data: keyValues,
        onAutocomplete: function (val) {
            // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
            AutoCompleteSelectHandler(val)
        },
        selectFirst: true

    })
```

This is working but I couldn't select its value. I tried to set it using .val(), .value , .text() etc. Is there any way to set its value by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `$("#autocompleteInput").autocomplete().val().data('autocomplete')` this for selecting a default value.

> AJAX, which stands for asynchronous JavaScript and XML, is a technique that allows web pages to be updated asynchronously, which means that the browser doesn't need to reload the entire page when only a small bit of data on the page has changed.

So what actually was happening is, when I was using dummy data, it was there already and working perfectly fine. But in ajax call, everything else gets loaded before getting data (please go through this [link about call stack](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-the-javascript-call-stack-861e41ae61d4/) to understand the behavior fully).

So what I did here is, after successfully getting the data then applied auto-complete.

Solution with ajax call:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            var chainageDataKeys = [];
            var chainageDataValues = [];
            var keyValues = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all", // dummy ajax calling
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                        if (index == 0) {
                            firstChainageVal = item.ccn3;
                        }
                        chainageDataKeys.push(item.ccn3);
                        chainageDataValues.push(null);
                    });
                    for (var i = 0; i < chainageDataKeys.length; i++) {
                        keyValues[chainageDataKeys[i]] = chainageDataValues[i];
                    }
                    //moved the autocomplete part here
                    $('#autocompleteInput').autocomplete({
                        data: keyValues,
                        onAutocomplete: function (val) {
                            // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
                        },
                        selectFirst: true
                    }).val(Object.keys(keyValues)[0]).data('autocomplete');
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="input-field col s12">
        <label for="autocompleteInput">Chainage Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="autocompleteInput">
    </div>
```

Solution With Dummy Data:

```js
//Just used some dummy data for testing

 var keyValues = 
{
"184": null,
"185.01": null,
"185.76": null,
"186.3": null
};

    $( "#autocompleteInput" ).autocomplete({
      data: keyValues,
        onAutocomplete: function (val) {
            // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
            
        },
        selectFirst: true
    }).val(Object.keys(keyValues)[0]).data('autocomplete'); 
    //this will take first item from keyValues as default value
    
    console.log(Object.keys(keyValues)[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="input-field col s12">
                <label for="autocompleteInput">Chainage Number</label>
                <input type="text" id="autocompleteInput">
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi @TBA , thank you for your response. I tried this at my end but it didn't work. I am using key value pair as dictionary . That might be the reason. So my KeyValues are like {"Number123",null}

Comment: @Jass What do you want to show as the default value? the whole key-value pair or just the key or value?

Comment: I want to show just "Number123". But while setting the data, I think we have to use both key and value

Comment: @Jass just to be clear, are you getting data like this - 
keyValues = [{key: key1, value: value1}, {key: key2, value: value2}]; ?

Comment: No @TBA, I'll just share documentation picture with you.

Comment: that would be great

Comment: $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
            "Apple": null,
            "Microsoft": null,
            "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
        },
    });

Comment: this is the syntax I found in material documentation. So I am doing it like that only. for eg {"Number123":null} is my key value pair

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work either.                                                                                         firstKey = Object.keys(keyValues)[0];
        $('#autocompleteInput').autocomplete({
            data: keyValues,
            onAutocomplete: function (val) {
                // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
                AutoCompleteSelectHandler(val)
            },
            selectFirst: true

        }).val(keyValues[firstKey]).data('autocomplete')

Comment: @Jass .val(Object.keys(keyValues)[0]).data('autocomplete') - try this and let me know if this works or not

Comment: tried, didn't work. I tried to log its value it shows 'undefined'

Comment: @Jass check the updated answer now, does it fulfill your requirements?

Comment: Yes it should work at my end if it's working here. But it's not!

Comment: do you know how to handle it if my key values contain decimal points?

Comment: when I try this, console.log(Object.keys(keyValues)[0]) , I get "undefined" . Is it because my keys are decimal numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238760/discussion-between-tba-and-jass).

Comment: @Jass hope this will solve your issue, check the updated answer please